# How can I lock my bot from being used in other guilds?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I want to be able to lock my discord bot so nobody can put it in there own server and use it. How would i go about this cause currently i have this code at the top of each command file and it doesn't work.

```
if (!message.guild.id === botconfig["bot_setup"].guild_id) {
        console.log(`I have left ${guild.name} as it does not match the server ID in the config file.\nThis bot only supports one server per-instance.`);
        return guild.leave();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

There is an easier way. If you don't want your bot to be added by other users you can just go to your particular **Discord Application** and then go to **Bot tab** and disable this setting.[image: Auth]

Answer (score 2):

You are inverting the guild id, if you invert an integer it will be transformed to a boolean and that will be false if the int was anything but zero. If you want your statement to work you need to check if its not equal like so:

```js
if (message.guild.id !== botconfig["bot_setup"].guild_id) {
  console.log(`I have left ${guild.name} as it does not match the server ID in the config file.\nThis bot only supports one server per-instance.`);
  return guild.leave();
}
```